# jquery how to regex css style positive to negative, negative to positive?

Tags: javascript, css, regex

jquery how to regex css style positive to negative, negative to positive?

```
var aaa='<p style="top:10px;left:-10px;">text</p>';
aaa.attr('style').replace(/\-/gi,'').replace(/\d+/gi,'-$&');//this will replace negative to positive, then positive to negative, so nothing change
```

But I need some effect like:

```
top:10px;left:-10px; => top:-10px;left:10px;
```

However, the style could be other rules. another example effection:

```
top:-100px;left:200px; => top:100px;left:-200px;
```

Comment: just multiply it by negative one?

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? It's seems to be a strange manipulation, do you really need a regular expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Rooster commented, use a function that multiply matched number with -1. The return value of the function is used as replacement string.

```
var aaa='<p style="top:10px;left:-10px;">text</p>';
aaa.replace(/[-\d]+/g, function(x) { return -parseInt(x); })
// => "<p style="top:-10px;left:10px;">text</p>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can do it like this :

```
$(aaa).css('left', function (i, value) {
    return -parseInt(value);
});
```

Here is a demo (click the red box) : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/s6M43/.

Answer (score 0):

I know your question was 'jquery how to regex css style positive to negative, negative to positive?' don't know what you want to achieve but maybe here is a css solution?

```
$('.content').click(function () {
$(this).toggleClass("left");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aronez/s6M43/4/

Greets